# After signing in debian9 show only Terminal

Tags: linux, debian, terminal

I'm totaly new in linux. I have debian9.13 which dont' show my taskbar after signing up, but only shows the Terminal which I cannot close or move.

I can still use python but i have no GUI for taskbar etc. The whole thing happend after a hardreset of the system.

A reset maybe will work but first I want to try to fix this without.

[image: Desktop]

Answer (score 0):

first of all run
`runlevel`
If It doesn't return 5 value
try `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`

If this still doesn't solve your issue try reinstalling gnome

`apt install --reinstall gnome`